# BitTorrent updates signaled as Potentially unwanted app found by Windows Security

Tags: windows, security, updates, bittorrent

Windows Security has detected **file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\BitTorrent\updates\7.10.5_46211.exe** as *potentially unwanted app*. What action should I perform for it - Allow or Quarantine or Remove?

Comment: It can be both false positive and a real virus. So for some reasons, i would suggest you to delete it, then uninstall bittorrent and reinstall from official website.

Comment: Remove it. Then uninstall BitTorrent. Then install qBittorrent from https://www.qbittorrent.org/ It is a better torrent client and free of malware. It is free and open source. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBittorrent

Comment: [Deluge BitTorrent Client](https://deluge-torrent.org/) is also free and open source.

Comment: Potentially unwanted App is just that, not a virus, it is something Microsoft considers as bad software, since bittorrent is mostly used for illegal content, Microsoft has marked most all bittorrent clients as unwanted. Add it to the exceptions list.-

Comment: "What action should I perform for it" - Upload the file to VirusTotal and based on the results take the appropriate action.